# setting up a mail server for my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, mx-record

Learning about how mailing works in general and I have the following question:
If I own the domain bigmoon.com and I want to have a mail address that looks like `bob@bigmoon.com`, as I understand it I can do the following:

1. Setup a mail server on a hosted machine A.
2. Create an A record that points mail.bigmoon.com to machine A.
3. Create an MX record that points bigmoon.com to mail.bigmoon.com.

Assuming I have content I want to serve from machine B on access to bigmoon.com, I can also configure an A record that points bigmoon.com to machine B. That way I can have content served from machine B to whoever surfs to bigmoon.com, but when mail is sent to bob@bigmoon.com it is redirected to mail.bigmoon.com where my mail server can handle it.

Did I get this correctly?

Comment: You cannot exchange messages with Microsoft if you offer *only* an IPv6, and younger services that refuse to trade in that weird deflationary currency of 32-bit numbers cannot exchange messages with you if you offer *only* IPv4. Right now, you want *both*, so setup `mail.example.com` with both A and AAAA records.

Comment: the question is more about the dns setup of mx records

Comment: Yes, you got that correct.